# custom object between activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to implement a three step process via 3 activities.

Activity A can proceed to Activity B

Activity B can proceed to Activity C, can return to previous Activity A

Activity C can return to Activity B

I have a custom object which is used to retained all the variables across A, B, C. When I proceed from A to B, I just pass it through the intent.putExtra(), likewise for B to C.

When I return from B to A or C to B, changes are lost. I use finish() to return to previous in current implementation.

I also need to take care of the back button in that no changes are lost.

How can I implement such behaviour:

navigate between A <--> B <--> C

and retaining the changes into the object? (page loads with information from object in onCreate()

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing this, you can't figure any?

Comment: I recommend you to documentate about startActivityForResult() 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

Comment: I did implement this in windows phone 8.1, but C# has pass by reference and from what I understand Java does not, so this method did not work. I tried startActivityForResult but it screwed up with the back button. I managed to get such behaviour simply by overriding the back button.

Answer (score 0):

you can override onResume() function of the activity and call those changing methods there.